# Faster builds by turning off all warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, compilation, warnings

I'm currently using Visual Studio for work builds. Say I'm not interested in any possible warnings--warnings and errors are dealt with on a different repository with a different team, etc. I just need to get the code, build it as quickly as possible, and run it.

Will it be faster if all warnings are turned off?

In Visual Studio, this is `Off: Turn Off All Warnings (/W0)`

I think GCC and other compilers have similar options.

I've wondered this a while, and could never find anyone asking the same question. Or the search string always found other questions with 'warnings' in it. I thought I'd ask in case anyone else ever wondered this.

*Edit:* It occurred to me that maybe others might think this is a dumb question. The reason I thought it was possible that turning off warnings could speed build time, was maybe it would prevent some warning-checking compile code from running, saving time. But if the warnings are always being checked for behind the scenes anyway, and it's just the printing of them that differs with warning level, then it is not much of an increase, *unless you have tons and tons of warnings*.

Comment: I'm guessing outputting a million warnings would take some time.

Comment: I have never heard of turning off warnings for speeding up compilation time.

Comment: As @chris suggests; I think the only difference would be related to the display of the warnings; the compiler itself is not doing much different.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I had wondered if turning off warnings would prevent some warning-checking compiler code from running, thus saving some time. But I guess it is only the printing of the warnings.

Comment: Aren't you ultimately responsible for cleaning these warning up?

Comment: @JohnDibling - as stated in the post, no. This is for when other people are handling that, or myself at another time, and I just need to get it from source to running asap. Most of it is not even my code.

Comment: The idea of committing something full of warnings just baffles me.

Comment: @JohnDibling Let me be clear: this is an old legacy app written by people I've never met. Part of my job includes running this for some purpose, and there is no time yet to fix it. Of course one should not do dumb things, but that is off topic to my question.

Comment: @nedshares:  I understand.  I've been in similar situations.  Just because it's not on-topic doesn't mean you can't *also* learn something from the tangential discussion.  If it were me, I'd `#pragma` those warnings away.  At least in my own translation units.

Comment: I wanted to add that there are not even many warnings (I saw 2 earlier). But my question is if, turning off the compiler-warning-checking logic, there may be any speedup noticed. @ThomasMatthews says it is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, turning off warnings will speed up the build process since the compiler does not have to perform printing.  Printing (displaying the text) takes time.

The question for the OP, is:  Is the time difference between printing with warnings on vs. printing without warnings negligible?

IMHO, unless the speed difference is in terms of tens of minutes, I find printing of warnings a good thing.  Any time savings under ten minutes is wasted during the day by unexpected meetings, unexpected conferences with colleagues or other overhead.

However, the cost of ignoring warnings may be higher than any profit gain by speeding up the build process.

Comment: Turning off warnings will only speed up the build process if there actually are warnings.  Otherwise, it's totally without effect.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I had wondered if turning off warnings would prevent some warning-checking compiler code from running, thus saving some time. But I guess it is only the printing of the warnings.

Comment: Whether or not the compiler performs warning checking is compiler dependent.  Turning off warnings may be as little as not displaying them (but the processing occurs anyway) or not performing the checks at all.  I believe it is the latter.  The language is parsed regardless, but handling the errors and warnings is a different process.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned gcc, the properly way for gcc to reduce compile time is to generate (and use) dependency file with -MMD -MP switch, so unnecessary re-compilation are skipped.

For Visual Studio, the next best thing is to enable incremental build, however keep in mind it sometime mess up for no reason.